# Android "Screenshot2" Tool NullPointerException on OSX 10.12

Tags: android, screenshot, testdroid

I'm trying to implement [bitbar's opencv library](https://github.com/bitbar/opencv-library) to do automated testing on Android devices. The library uses Android's "screenshot2" tool. But whenever I run it either through the library or directly from the terminal on OSX 10.12 I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.wakeup(MonitorThread.java:453)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.quit(MonitorThread.java:461)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AndroidDebugBridge.terminate(AndroidDebugBridge.java:293)
    at com.android.screenshot.Screenshot.main(Screenshot.java:280)
```

I'm using version 26.1.1 of Android SDK tools and JDK 8u151

Comment: How do you call it?

Comment: Just from the terminal:
`screenshot2 -s [serial of my device] screencap.png`

Comment: Must be something wrong with the OS or SDK itself. I would try to decompile Screenshot.class and check line 280